# What's wrong with this OpenGL model picking code?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics-programming

I am making simple model viewer using OpenGL. When I want to pick an object OpenGL returns nothing or an object that is in another place.

This is my code:

```
GLuint buff[1024] = {0};
GLint hits,view[4];

glSelectBuffer(1024,buff);
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, view);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
gluPickMatrix(x,y,1.0,1.0,view);
gluPerspective(45,(float)view[2]/(float)view[4],1.0,1500.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glRenderMode(GL_SELECT);

glLoadIdentity();
//I make the same transformations for normal render
glTranslatef(0, 0, -zoom);
glMultMatrixf(transform.M);
glInitNames();
glPushName(-1);
for(int j=0;j<allNodes.size();j++)
{
    glLoadName(allNodes.at(j)->id);
    allNodes.at(j)->Draw(textures);
}
glPopName();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
hits = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an ATI card? I think they deprecated some portions of OpenGL (picking included) a long time ago.

Comment: I have Ati on laptop :/ Thx :/ I will check this

Comment: So what can I use ? Test collision mouse-ray with triangles from meshes ?

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to do you own picking. If you want tight results use triangle picking, or you can test against bounding boxes/spheres if you don't need that much precision.

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL picking using the selection buffer is deprecated. If your scene is small enough, you should use [colour-based picking](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/index.php3?color1); otherwise, you can use [gluUnProject](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml) to obtain a world coordinate from a mouse coordinate and a depth read from the depth buffer using `glReadPixels()`.

Answer (score 0):

No one use OpenGL picking this days, you have to implement it yourself. Transforming from camera to worlds space is a bit tricky, here is a good article http://trac.bookofhook.com/bookofhook/trac.cgi/wiki/MousePicking

Answer (score 0):

Ok, but for 3d viewer application opengl isn't better ? 
My doesn't work, beacouse I have two mistakes:
**1.**

```
gluPerspective(45,(float)view[2]/(float)view[3],1.0,1500.0);
```

**2.**

```
gluPickMatrix(x,view[3]-y,1.0,1.0,view);
```

So it is looking that picking still works on ati, my friend said my that picking can be making by software implementation of opengl.